# Elasticsearch Range Query on Nested Keyword field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6, elasticsearch-nested

I'm trying to run a range query on a nested keyword field in Elasticsearch 6.4, but I'm not having any luck:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "metas",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  { "term": { "metas.key": "duration"} },
                  { "range": {"metas.value": {"gte": "100", "lte": "200"} } }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So I'm looking for all documents where `metas.key` is `duration` and `metas.value` is between `100-200` (formatted as string).
My query is successful, but includes any `metas.value` regardless of it's value, I'm e.g. getting documents where the value is `20` etc.
My mapping (in Ruby) looks like this:

```
indexes :metas, type: :nested do
  indexes :key, type: :keyword
  indexes :value, type: :keyword
  indexes :created_at, type: :date
  indexes :updated_at, type: :date
end
```

Comment: Data type for `metas.value` should be `integer` and not string i.e.(`text`/`keyword`)

Comment: According to the Elasticsearch doc, it should be possible to use the range query on strings: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/query-dsl-range-query.html > The type of the Lucene query depends on the field type, for string fields, the TermRangeQuery, while for number/date fields, the query is a NumericRangeQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Nishant mentioned in the comment, you need to change the type to a [numeric datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/number.html).

[The Range Query documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/query-dsl-range-query.html) states:

> Matches documents with fields that have terms within a certain range.
>   The type of the Lucene query depends on the field type, for `string`
>   fields, the `TermRangeQuery`, while for number/date fields, the query is
>   a `NumericRangeQuery`.

So when you have a `keyword` (which is a `string` type) Elasticsearch is using `TermRangeQuery` for comparison and there the alphabetical order is taken. Alphabetically the 20 is between 100 and 200.